# how to edit data frames and convert to a list(pandas, read_html())?

Tags: python

I used library pandas, read_html() to import a table from a webpage.
I want to insert values from table read_html in ms msl table
but for this I must edit table read_html and convert to list.
This is difficult to do because .read_html() produces a list of dataframes.

my python code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
r = requests.get('URL')
pd.set_option('max_rows',10000) 
df = pd.read_html(r.content)
print(df)
```

result print(df) - dataframes:

```
[             0                     1              2   3
0        Number                  Name           Plan NaN
1          NaN                   NaN   not(selected) NaN
2     53494580          + (53)494580         551 NaN
3     53494581          + (53)494581         551 NaN
4     53494582          + (53)494582         551 NaN
5     55110000          + (53)494583         551 NaN]
```

I would like the following results to be written to the ms msl table:

```
[['1','NaN','NaN','not(selected)','NaN'],
['2','53494580','+ (53)494580','NP_551','NaN'],
['3','53494581','+ (53)494581','NP_551','NaN'],
['4','53494582','+ (53)494582','NP_551','NaN'],
['5','55110000','+ (53)494583','NP_551','NaN]']
```

how to edit data frames and convert to a list?
I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was mentioned in other answer you should select dataframe using:

```
df = pd.read_html(r.content, header=0)[0]
```

Then, to turn it into matrix just use:

```
df.as_matrix()
```

This will give you numpy `ndarray` that could be turned into nested list via:

```
df.as_matrix().tolist()
```

Comment: It is true that you solved the issue and I just enhanced it with a method. Do you take +1 as an apology? :)

Comment: I took back the upvote, will add it tomorrow if it's okay :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need parameter `header` for first row to columns names and then `[0]` for select first value of `list` - it return `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.read_html(r.content, header=0)[0]
```

For `list`s use [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) with `tolist`:

```
arr = df.values.tolist()
```